# Can't change the background color through java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im trying to make a settings activity from which the user can change the background color of the main activity... here is my java code, everything with the xml is fine 
the target activity to change the background to is not the one with the radio buttons

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


ConstraintLayout loginContainer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    loginContainer = findViewById(R.id.loginContainer);
}

public void onColorRadioClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
    RadioButton btn1 = findViewById(R.id.colorRadio1);
    RadioButton btn2 = findViewById(R.id.colorRadio2);
    RadioButton btn3 = findViewById(R.id.colorRadio3);

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.colorRadio1:
            if (checked)
                btn2.setChecked(false);
                btn3.setChecked(false);
                loginContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.wallBack1));
                break;
        case R.id.colorRadio2:
            if (checked)
                btn1.setChecked(false);
                btn3.setChecked(false);
                loginContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.wallBack2));
            break;
        case R.id.colorRadio3:
            if (checked)
                btn1.setChecked(false);
                btn2.setChecked(false);
                loginContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.wallBack3));
            break;
    }
}

}
```

whenever i click a radio button, at first (without trying to change the color) everything worked but now after ive added those lines, everytime i click it crashes saying it couldnt execute method for android:onClick

the error in the Run section

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.roeie.renote, PID: 2590
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:122)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:122) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
                  at com.example.roeie.renote.SettingsActivity.onColorRadioClicked(SettingsActivity.java:34)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:122) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

The Radio Buttons XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.roeie.renote.SettingsActivity"
android:background="@color/wallBack1">

<RadioButton
    android:onClick="onColorRadioClicked"
    android:id="@+id/colorRadio1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="RadioButton"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<RadioButton
    android:onClick="onColorRadioClicked"
    android:id="@+id/colorRadio2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="RadioButton"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/colorRadio1" />

<RadioButton
    android:onClick="onColorRadioClicked"
    android:id="@+id/colorRadio3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="RadioButton"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/colorRadio2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

the xml of the activity that needs to be changed is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/loginContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/wallBack1"
tools:context="com.example.roeie.renote.LoginActivity">

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="RENOTE"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/fui_bgGoogle"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.223" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/signInBtn"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape_1"
    android:onClick="signInClick"
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:textColor="@color/wallBack1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/signOutBtn"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.977" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/signOutBtn"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape_1_rev"
    android:onClick="signOutClick"
    android:text="Sign Out"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.928" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_settings_white"
    android:onClick="settingsBtnClick"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<!--android:background="@drawable/button_shape_1"-->
```

Comment: please post your log cat

Comment: The crash may be happening because you forgot braces on your multiple lines if blocks...

Comment: Kindly post your logcats

Comment: Please add your logcat and xml

Comment: post your error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your id is missing from the ConstraintLayout in root whose background you want to change.

> android:id="@+id/loginContainer"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.roeie.renote.SettingsActivity"
android:id="@+id/loginContainer"
android:background="@color/wallBack1">

<RadioButton
    android:onClick="onColorRadioClicked"
    android:id="@+id/colorRadio1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="RadioButton"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<RadioButton
    android:onClick="onColorRadioClicked"
    android:id="@+id/colorRadio2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="RadioButton"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/colorRadio1" />

<RadioButton
    android:onClick="onColorRadioClicked"
    android:id="@+id/colorRadio3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:text="RadioButton"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/colorRadio2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Edit: If you want to change **MainActivity** background from settings activity then save it in some **preference** and apply **onStart()** of the main activity whenever it's active.

Or

You can start your settings activity as **[startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)()** and then get the background drawable selected in **onActivityResult()** from intent data and then change it.

**EDIT: Sample code**

first, start your settings activity like this.

```
  Intent selectColor = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
  startActivityForResult(selectColor, 101);
```

after selection call this method and pass the color id selected

```
public void setImageSelected(int colorID){
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("SELECTED_COLOR", colorID);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
}
```

and get the result back like this.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == 101) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           //here get the selected id using
           int colorID = data.getIntExtra("SELECTED_COLOR", 0);
          //use it to set the background here
        }
    }
}
```

To get the background color

```
int colorSelected = ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.selectedColor);
```

Comment: does the **OnActivityResult()** need to be in the java of the MainActivity or the SettingsActivity? @vikas kumar

Comment: OnActivityResult() should be in MainActivity and child activity should setResult(RESULT_OK,intent); the passed intent will have the data which will be available onActivityResult as parameter.

Comment: where do i put **setResult(...,intent)**?

Comment: i'm posting a sample you will get in a moment.

Comment: omg thank so much, btw is there a way to change a color resource value using code? because that would be amazing

Comment: the answer is no you can't change the compiled color code but you can use it to manipulate the values locally at runtime using java. you can save it in shared preference anyways and modify based on conditions anytime.

Comment: but you can use firebase library remote config. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/

Comment: @vikasSmith is there a way to change a value in remote config through java without needing to creating a new xml file?

Answer (score 1):

wrape your if statement with `{}`

```
 switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.colorRadio1:
                if (checked){
                    btn2.setChecked(false);
                    btn3.setChecked(false);
                    loginContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.wallBack1));
                    }
                    break;
            case R.id.colorRadio2:
                if (checked){
                    btn1.setChecked(false);
                    btn3.setChecked(false);
                    loginContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.wallBack2));
                }
                break;
            case R.id.colorRadio3:
                if (checked){
                    btn1.setChecked(false);
                    btn2.setChecked(false);
                    loginContainer.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.wallBack3));
                  }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: its not the problem, as long as the indentation is correct then the if is executable

Comment: make sure you have `R.id.loginContainer` in `activity_settings` xml Layout

Comment: put id for constrainLayout `android:id="@+id/loginContainer"`

Comment: okay then it's not directly possible by this you need to store selected value in some prefrence or else and  in your main activity change color value according that

Comment: ive thought about it but changing colot value **is** actually not possible... its something that is not supposed to happen although there is a way by overriding a class but there must be an easier way

Answer (score 1):

Remove your ids from onColorRadioClicked method

```
RadioButton btn1 = findViewById(R.id.colorRadio1);
RadioButton btn2 = findViewById(R.id.colorRadio2);
RadioButton btn3 = findViewById(R.id.colorRadio3);
```

and put it inside OnCreate

Answer (score 1):

In OnCreate method

```
loginContainer = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.loginContainer);
RadioButton btn1 = (RadioButton )findViewById(R.id.colorRadio1);
RadioButton btn2 = (RadioButton )findViewById(R.id.colorRadio2);
RadioButton btn3 = (RadioButton )findViewById(R.id.colorRadio3);
```

In XML

```
android:id="@+id/loginContainer"
```